# Storybook, Angular, and Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-storybook

I am creating stories based on reusable form components. I am trying to pass different FormControls into different stories based on the same template and component.

I am able to pass in the FormControl, directly to the template, like so:

```
import { moduleMetadata, Meta, Story } from '@storybook/angular';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
  FormControl,
  FormsModule,
  FormBuilder,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  AbstractControl,
  FormGroup,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { MyRadiobuttonComponent } from '../../../projects/my-angular/src/lib/radiobutton/radiobutton.component';

const radioForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
  radioFCchecked: new FormControl('value1', []),
});

export default {
  title: 'Angular Component Library/Radiobutton',
  component: MyRadiobuttonComponent,
  decorators: [
    moduleMetadata({
      declarations: [MyRadiobuttonComponent],
      imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
    }),
  ],
} as Meta;

const Template: Story = (args) => ({
  props: {
    ...args,
    parentFormGroup: radioForm,
    ctrl: radioForm.controls.radioFCchecked,
  },
});
```

And this works. But the downside is I can only pass in one FormControl to the [ctrl] property. But if I move it to the args like so, I get an error:

`Error: Converting circular structure to JSON`

```
export const Selected = Template.bind({});
Selected.args = {
  id: 'radio1',
  isRequired: false,
  label: 'Radio Selected',
  value: 'value1',
  ctrl: radioForm.controls.radioFCchecked,
};
```

How can I pass different FormControls, and ideally, multiple FormControls into different stories referencing the same component?

EDIT: Here is the custom component, for reference:

mycomponent.component.html

```
<div class="form-check" [ngClass]="{ 'form-check-inline': isInline }">
  <input
    [id]="id"
    type="radio"
    [value]="value"
    [formControl]="ctrl"
    [name]="ctrl"
  />
  <label class="form-check-label" [for]="id">
    {{ label }}<span *ngIf="isRequired" class="asterisk"> *</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

mycomponent.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-radiobutton',
  templateUrl: './radiobutton.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./radiobutton.component.scss'],
})
export class MyRadiobuttonComponent {
  @Input() label!: string;
  @Input() ctrl!: any;
  @Input() value!: string;
  @Input() id!: string;
  @Input() isInline: boolean = false;
  @Input() isRequired: boolean = false;
}
```

Comment: You might be able to solve this by using a template and wrapping your component in a FormGroup. I have done something similar to this and then specified the formGroup in the params.